# comparing port numbers of packets in python

Tags: python, scapy

```
from scapy.all import *
def print_summary(pkt):
     for i in pkt:
          sport=[pkt[TCP].sport]
          if (sport[i]!=sport[i+1]):
             packet=sport
             print packet    

sniff(offline="/root/ip2.pcap",prn = print_summary)
```

Comment: Can you write some description or output that you desire or at least some errors ?

Comment: from scapy.all import *
a=[]
def print_summary(pkt):
     sport=[pkt[TCP].sport]
     for i in sport:
       a.append(sport)
     print a

sniff(offline="/root/ip2.pcap", prn=print_summary,count=5)

Comment: For the above code, i am getting output as                                                                                                [[27887]]
[[27887], [49792]]
[[27887], [49792], [60476]]
[[27887], [49792], [60476], [52345]]
[[27887], [49792], [60476], [52345], [22070]]

Comment: It is appending and printing every time. How can i print after all iterations, i.e, only the last appended data

Answer (score 0):

You could use rdpcap to read the .pcap file, create a list, and append the port number to the list after checking if it is already there or not.

```
from scapy.all import *

pcap = rdpcap('test_pcap.pcap')
ports = []

for pkt in pcap:
    if pkt.haslayer(TCP):
        if pkt.sport in ports:
            pass
        else:
            ports.append(pkt.sport)

print(ports)
```